# float to integer in python

Tags: python, floating-point, integer, absolute-value

If I want to convert a float to an integer in Python, what function do I use?

The problem is that I have to use a variable passed through the function `math.fabs` (Absolute Value) as an index for a list, so it has to be an `int`, while the function `math.fabs` returns a `float`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `int()` constructor:

```
>>> foo = 7.6
>>> int(foo)
7
```

Note that if you use the [built-in `abs()` function](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#abs) with an integer argument, you'll get an integer result in the first place:

```
>>> type(abs(-7))
<type 'int'>
```

Answer (score 2):

Probably you're looking for both [`round`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#round) and [`int`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#int):

```
>>> foo = 1.9
>>> int(foo)
1
>>> int(round(foo))
2
```